# Spring Data Rest with JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to secure a simple Spring-Data-Rest app using jwt. 
Taking the seed from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security

The SecurityConfig is below (using normal username, password authentication)
How can I change this to **JWT Authentication**?

(Authorization is already done using `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` in repositories)

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  /**
   * This section defines the user accounts which can be used for
   * authentication as well as the roles each user has.
   */
  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("greg").password("turnquist").roles("USER").and()
      .withUser("ollie").password("gierke").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
  }

  /**
   * This section defines the security policy for the app.
   * - BASIC authentication is supported (enough for this REST-based demo)
   * - /employees is secured using URL security shown below
   * - CSRF headers are disabled since we are only testing the REST interface,
   *   not a web one.
   *
   * NOTE: GET is not shown which defaults to permitted.
   */
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
      .httpBasic().and()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/employees").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/employees/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/employees/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and()
      .csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a good tutorial for JWT Authentication in spring boot, but in can applied for spring applications as well: https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/

According to the tutorial in your SecurityConfiguration.configure you need

```
http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

`JWTAuthenticationFilter` extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, is applied to /login URL and generates JWT token based on your login/password if such a user exists in the system.

`JWTAuthorizationFilter` verifies JWT token coming in http header

Of course you need to add more moving parts in order to enable JWT auth by this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the tutorial for Spring Security OAuth:
https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

In particular you have to enable the resource server. This is my (modified) configuration):

```
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        try {
            // Load the public key of the authorization server.
            String key = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResource("/reng0-public.key"), Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
            converter.setVerifierKey(key);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

The client has to add the Authorization: Bearer header to make it work.